# How to solve this ,string cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json

I am android learning,I am using Json parsing and getting problem like below how to remove this problem?

org.json.JSONException: Value SELECT of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

here is my code

```
public EventListStatus eventListParser(String response) {
    String msg = null;
    String status = null;
    EventListStatus eventListStatus = new EventListStatus();
    ArrayList<EventList> eventLists = new ArrayList<EventList>();
    eventLists.clear();
    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
        status = jo.getString("status");
        msg = jo.getString("msg");
        eventListStatus.setErrorCode(jo.getString("errorCode"));
        eventListStatus.setErroDesc(jo.getString("errorDesc"));
        eventListStatus.setMsg(msg);
        eventListStatus.setMsg(status);
        if(msg != null && msg.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
        {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jo.getString("data"));
            for(int j=0;j<ja.length();j++){
                JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject(ja.getString(j));
                EventList el = new EventList();
                el.setID(jo1.getString("ID"));
                el.setPost_title(jo1.getString("post_title"));
                el.setPost_date(jo1.getString("post_date"));
                el.setDescription(jo1.getString("description"));
                el.setPost_content(jo1.getString("post_content"));
                el.setGuid(jo1.getString("guid"));
                el.setStart_date(jo1.getString("start_date"));
                el.setEnd_date(jo1.getString("end_date"));
                el.setLocation(jo1.getString("location"));
                el.setGeo_location(jo1.getString("geo_location"));
                el.setLatitude(jo1.getString("latitude"));
                el.setLongitude(jo1.getString("longitude"));
                el.setPhone(jo1.getString("phone"));
                el.setStime(jo1.getString("stime"));
                el.setEtime(jo1.getString("etime"));
                el.setVenue(jo1.getString("venue"));
                eventLists.add(el);
            }
            eventListStatus.setEventLists(eventLists);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return eventListStatus;
}
```

here is my json response

```
  {"status": 1,
  "msg": "success",
  "errorCode": "",
  "errorDesc": "",
  "data": [
    {
      "sdate": "2016-02-05",
      "ID": "3366",
      "post_title": "Guided Tours of Louis Armstrong House",
      "post_date": "2016-01-15 18:30:30",
      "description": "\r\n\tEvery Friday\r\n",
      "post_content": "\r\n\tEvery Friday\r\n",
      "guid": "http://hothousejazz.com/event_detail.php?eid=3366",
      "start_date": "2016-02-05",
      "end_date": "2016-03-04",
      "evo_hide_endtime": "No",
      "venue": "Queens",
      "location": "34-56 107th Street, Corona, NY",
      "geo_location": "34-56 107th Street, Corona, NY",
      "latitude": "40.754596",
      "longitude": "-73.8613472",
      "phone": "718-478-8274",
      "stime": "10:00 AM",
      "etime": "05:00 PM",
      "website": "http://www.louisarmstronghouse.org"
    }
```

here is log

```
02-09 01:12:41.399 1979-2009/? W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value SELECT of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: may your string (response) is not in JSON format post your response

Comment: post your json format

Comment: Your JSON is not well formed that is why it is not being converted into JSON object. You need to add ']}' at the end of the given JSON and then try.

Comment: have already add because this is array type I sent only one  so..

Comment: I have added my log, please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
Jsonobject jsonobj=new Jsonobject(response)
Jsonarray jsonarray=new Jsonarray(jsonobj.getString("status"));
for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
{
Here you can fetch the  other values inside Jsonarray

}
```

This is the approach for parsing json but your json is not formatted well please take a look at it

Comment: why set jsonobj.getString("status")); because my json array start from "data"

Comment: you can't convert string `status` to `Jsonarray`

Answer (score 0):

fatch Data like this

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

 String  status = jsonObject.getString("msg");
  if (status.equals("success")){

  JSONArray cast = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

  for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++){

  JSONObject actor2 = cast.getJSONObject(i);
  String name =actor2.getString("sdate");
  String note = actor2.getString("id");
  String point = actor2.getString("post_title");
  String has_image = actor2.getString("post_date");

}
```

Try This.

Comment: hello again got error like Value SELECT of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: On which line @Vishal

Comment: JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: hello,again I am facing that problem

Comment: what is the problem? @Vishal

Comment: Value SELECT of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject